# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post() with ajax

Tags: ajax, wp-head, wp-blog-header.php

I have an `index.php` page with about link, which will get about author content from created page (post) inside WordPress dashboard with name about. I'm using [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) plugin for poups. 
I have `about.php` which includes content of about page like this:

```
<?php 
  $pageid = 2; // 2 is the id of about page/post
  $about = get_post($pageid);
?>

<div id="custom-content" class="white-popup-block" style="max-width:600px; margin: 20px auto;">

    <h3><?php echo $about->post_title; ?></h3>
    <style>
    #custom-content img {max-width: 100%;margin-bottom: 10px;}
    </style>
    <div class="image-container pull-left">
        <img src="<?php echo get_field( "image", $pageid ); ?>">
    </div>
    <h4><?php echo get_field( "brief", $pageid ); ?></h4>
    <p>
    <?php echo get_field( "brief_lines", $pageid ); ?>
    </p>
    <div class="about-content">
        <?php echo $about->post_content; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in `index.php`

```
<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/about.php" class="morelink pull-left text-ajax-popup">read more</a>
```

and in the `footer.php`

```
$('.text-ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  alignTop: true,
  overflowY: 'scroll' 
});
```

After click on the link I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post()

Is there files could I include inside `about.php`? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `about.php` is not a recognized file by WordPress and won't load any of the actual WordPress functions. `<?php wp_header(); ?>` in your themes `header.php` file actually loads most the WordPress functionality that you're used to using. Since you're not calling either `get_header()` OR `wp_header()` in your `about.php` file you don't actually have access to any of the WordPress functionality. One solution to this would be to include a core WordPress file at the top of your post which will give you this kind of access:

This file: `require('/wp-blog-header.php');`

The required file is located in the root of WordPress, same place as `wp-config.php` - I believe this will load what you need.

Here's a list of [Recognized Template Files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

## What should do though...

Is find a way to use the build in [`wp_ajax`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) functionality to get your page and bring it back. Then there's no extra file, no need to require `wp-blog-header.php` and it hook / function would be conveniently located in your themes `functions.php` file